# Почему не находится файл, если он есть?

Tags: php, javascript

Я всегда получаю `not exists` даже если файл есть. - Что не так ?

```
function checkedFile() {
 var fileName = 'file.php';
 var checked = <?php $filename = $_GET["fileName"]; if (file_exists($filename)) { echo "'exists'"; } else { echo "'not exists'"; }?>;
 console.log(checked);
}

setInterval(function(){checkedFile()},500);
```

Comment: Потому что "Все смешалось в доме Облонских"(с) Что-то вы смешали JS и php, каким-то особо извращенным способом.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а как иначе ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно делать честный запрос на апи, и проверять файл на сервере, а не на клиенте

```
function checkedFile() {
 var fileName = 'file.php?fileName=имя_файла';
 fetch(fileName).then(result => result.text())
   .then(console.log)
}

setInterval(function(){checkedFile()},500);
```

А на стороне сервера уже проверяйте, что файл существует

```
filename = $_GET["fileName"];
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  echo "'exists'";
} else {
  echo "'not exists'";
}
```

Comment: Кажется, этот пример упадет при попытке парса json'ки, которая и не json'ка вовсе. А в остальном плюсую.

Comment: А откуда в `$_GET["fileName"]` появятся данные, если вы их в `fetch` не передаете?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko поправил